# Gameobject​ timer in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a unity game to where there is a gameobject(let's say a ball) and after  an allotted amount of time(5 sec) that gameobject disappears, any clue on the code??

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to achieve that is to use Unity's built-in [`Destroy()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) method. 
You can pass your object and a timer (in seconds) as arguments.

```
Destroy(gameObject, 5); // destroys the gameObject after 5 seconds elapsed
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try to use the Invoke method, which will call the method you specify after some time.

```
void Start()
{
    Invoke("DestroyMyObject", 5);
}

void DestroyMyObject()
{
    this.Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

If you want to call some method repeatedly, you could use InvokeRepeating
Here is the whole documentation:

[Invoke docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html)

[InvokeRepeating docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html)

Comment: Now let's say I want to also have it we're every 2 seconds a clone of the ball would appear with a new time on that clone counting down from 5, how would I do that?

Comment: Just edited the answer. If you want to call every two second a method to clone the ball, you could use InvokeRepeating.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an coroutine for the timer. This is a bit more complicated than other answers, but it is good practice for using coroutines. For example:

```
IEnumerator DestroyObject(GameObject object, int time) {
yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
Destroy(object);
}
```

If this script is attached to a controller or anything else that isn't the player:

```
public GameObject player;

//Wherever the player is supposed to be destroyed 
{
DestroyObject(player, 5);
}
```

If this script is attached to the player:

```
//Wherever the player is supposed to be destroyed
{
DestroyObject(this.gameObject, 5);
}
```